# Mouse position on 'dragover'

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, mouse-position

Trying to get mousePosition with object (file), which is dragged from a desktop and later dropped on on my internet browser, but both values i get is "undefined"

small html

```
 <body>Drag something on body(it is kinda small) and open concole</body>
```

script

```
var dragX =-1;
var dragY = -1;

    $("body").bind("dragover", function(e){
     dragX = e.pageX;
     dragY = e.pageY;

    console.log("X: "+dragX+" Y: "+dragY);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found my problem:
this:

```
 var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;
```

with this

```
var dragX = e.originalEvent.pageX, dragY = e.originalEvent.pageY;
```

Comment: Life save. i spent a day for this :D :D